# stop audio using jquery by the event of slide change

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, drupal

In my drupal site a slider is there.each slide contains an audio player. my requirement is audio has to stop when slide changes. the slider i am using is owlCarousel slider.my current code is

```
$("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
    afterAction: function syncPosition() {
        document.getElementById('t_audio').pause();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

can anybody help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need to use an IIFE here, so you can remove the `(jQuery)` at the end of the code. Similarly, you can supply an anonymous function to `afterAction` so `syncPosition` is redundant.

Finally, jQuery doesn't have a `pause()` method - even for `audio` elements, so even if you selected the element using jQuery you would still need to call `pause` on the underlying DOMElement. Try this:

```
$("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
    afterAction: function() {
        $('#t_audio')[0].pause();
    });
});
```

Comment: thnks for d answer @Rory McCrossan. i got it by d following     code..$('audio').each(function(){
    this.pause();
    this.currentTime = 0;